# Intel MPI_SIZEOF not working for Fortran complex type

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

Given the following fortran code:

```
integer, parameter :: double = kind(1.0d0)

integer :: integerTest
real(double) :: doubleTest
complex(double) :: complexTest
integer :: testSize
integer :: ierr

integerTest = 0
doubleTest = real(0.d0, kind=double)
complexTest = cmplx(0.d0, 0.d0, kind=double)

call MPI_SIZEOF(integerTest, testSize, ierr)
! ...
call MPI_SIZEOF(doubleTest, testSize, ierr)
! ...
call MPI_SIZEOF(complexTest, testSize, ierr)
```

When compiling with Intel MPI, I get the error:

```
error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call. [MPI_SIZEOF]
```

on the line

```
 call MPI_SIZEOF(complexTest, testSize, ierr)
```

This code compiles and executes with no issue using OpenMPI. What is the cause of this error? It seems like it's looking for a specific match for the type of `complexTest`, but isn't the whole point of `MPI_SIZEOF` is to work generically with nearly any type?

Comment: Declaring `complexTest` as type `complex` with no `kind` works, but it's not a solution.

Comment: It also fails if I declare `complexTest` as `double complex`.

Comment: Might be a bug in Intel MPI. You should be able to use the `storage_size()` standard Fortran intrinsic instead (just convert to bytes).

Comment: Do you use `use mpi` or `include "mpif.h"`?

Comment: Definitely an omission. `MPI_COMPLEX16` is among the predefined datatypes in Intel MPI (at least its handle is found in `mpif.h`) and the lack of a specific subroutine for `MPI_SIZEOF` looks like an error to me. Report to Intel.

Comment: Apparently, `MPI_SIZEOF` in Intel MPI supports a very limited set of intrinsic types - see my last comment to Vladimir's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a bug in the MPI library, they might have forgotten to add this specific function to the module. BTW *"nearly any type"* is certainly wrong, `MPI_SIZEOF` is only intended to work for intrinsic types.

As a workaround you can use

```
testSize = storage_size(complexTest) / character_storage_size
```

(or just `/ 8`)

Comment: According to the standard, it should work for any intrinsic Fortran type, not only numeric ones.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have " IN x a Fortran variable of numeric intrinsic type (choice)" in MPI 3.1 p.628.

Comment: Although I can't see a reason why not include logical and character. Derived intrinsic types are probably not terribly useful.

Comment: True, but the sentence above reads "any Fortran intrinsic type". I took the liberty of reversing `mpi_sizeofs.mod` from Intel MPI 5.1 (hopefully Intel won't sue me) and from the names of the specific subroutines I would guess that the generic accepts scalars and 1d arrays of `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `LOGICAL`, `CHARACTER`, `COMPLEX`, `DOUBLE`, `INTEGER*1`, `INTEGER*2`, and `INTEGER*8` for `X`.